# Locking thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, thread-safety

In my C# project I m using the Timer.One(keyboard_timer) is for to watch if a user press F8 or not and another Timer(clipboard_time) is to watch if Clipboard contains a text or not.In my project The keyboard is always enable and the clipboard_timer is enabled when a user press F8.If the user again press F8 the clipboard_timer is disabled.what my project does that  When  user press F8 and he copies a word then my project show the meaning of the copied word in a window.my program runs on the background and always check if a user press F8 if he does then all-time my program  check the clipboard, if it contains a text(word) if it does the show the meaning of the word everytime.
 My code is here:

On the initialize

```
   keyboard_timer.Enabled = true;
        keyboard_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(keyboard_timer_Tick);
```

then

```
  public void keyboard_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // clipboard enable
        if ((a % 2) != 0)
        {
      //  F9 is for Easy mood to eanble

             if ((GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F9) == -32767) && hot_key == "F9")
            {
                label2.Text = "Easy";
                online_clipboard_active = "";
                Clipboard.Clear();
                clipboard_timer.Enabled = true;
                clipboard_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(clipboard_timer_Tick);
               ++a;           
            }


    ///// // F8 is for online Mood
            else if ((GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F8) == -32767) && online_hot_key == "F8")
            {
                label2.Text = "Online";
                online_clipboard_active = "on";
                clipboard_timer.Enabled = true;                    
                clipboard_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(clipboard_timer_Tick);

                ++a;

            }

        }// end of enable 


        //clipboard disable
        if ((a % 2) == 0) // 
        {
            // F9 is for Easy mood to disable here
            if ((GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F9) == -32767) && hot_key == "F9")
            {
                   label2.Text = "Off";
                    clipboard_timer.Enabled = false;
                    ++a;
            }

            // F8 is for online Mood to disable here
             else  if ((GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F8) == -32767) && online_hot_key == "F8")
            {
                label2.Text = "Off";
                online_clipboard_active = "";
                clipboard_timer.Enabled = false;
               ++a;                   
            }

        }//end of clipboard disable

    }// end of keyboard timer
```

Clipboard timer is

```
 public void clipboard_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            string x = Clipboard.GetText();
            Clipboard.Clear();

            if ((a%2)==0 && online_clipboard_active == "on")
            {
                //cal online_mood form to translate the string from googletranslator
                online_mood o = new online_mood(x);
                o.Show();
            }

            else if((a%2)==0 && online_clipboard_active == "")
            {
                //cal show_meaning form to show the meaning into a window
                show_meaning s = new show_meaning(x);
                s.Show();
            }        
        }

    }// end of clipboard timer Tick
```

I want that when clipboard timer enable on that time keyboard timer will be lock because both of them uses a variable. When clipboard timer runs then keyboard timer will be lock and then when clipboard timer finished it works then the keyboard timer will be reactivated How can I solve this?
Anyone give me any help?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple locking can be accomplish with a static member.

```
private static readonly object Sync = new object();
```

and then before setting or getting the info use

```
lock(Sync)
```

to lock the variable.

BTW: I don't get what you are trying to do. Maybe you should use the Keypress event of the form instead of the timers.

Comment: my program runs on the background and always check if a user press F8 if he does then check the clipboard if it contains a text(word) if it does the show the meaning of the word

Answer (score 0):

Look into [C# locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

you basicly do this:

```
public Object lockObject = new Object(); //You want a separate object so that it's not changed when lock is active


...    
//Code that can be run by any number of thread at the same time
...

lock(lockObject)
{
     ...
     //Code that is accessable by only one thread at a time:
     ...
}

...    
//Code that can be run by any number of thread at the same time
...
```

Hope this helps you out a bit.